# Codeigniter 3 multiple Ajax from 2 different pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am in desperate need of a code review and I don't know where else to ask this, but here.

First, let me explain what I am doing: I have a user profile page that will display users comments. Users can like, dislike, or reply to comments.

Next, I will explain how I do this: I have a 'profile' controller that loads the 'profile' view. Once the profile view is loaded I make an ajax call to load the comments that will append the results which is basically another view I created called profile_posts (comments). Once the profile_posts has been appended I am then making another ajax call for each comment on the page to retrieve the number of likes and dislikes as well as if the user viewing the page has liked/disliked a comment to change the color.

Now, the problem that I am having: I have successfully gotten everything to work, but the problem is that I am making an ajax call for each comment which is taking a total of 60 sec to load all data - way too long so I know I am not doing something right.

Here is my code:

**Controller:**

```
function profile($identity = NULL)
{
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        // redirect them to the login page
        redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
    }
    else
    {       
        // page title
        $data['title'] = "Profile";

        // get the id of the profile we're viewing
        $profile = $this->user_model->get_profile_id($identity);        
        $profile_id = $profile->id;

        // set the username of the profile we're viewing
        $data['username'] = $identity;

        // get the logged in user data
        $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row(); 

        // get the id of the user making the post
        $data['user_id'] = $user->id;             

        $this->_render_page('user/profile', $data);
    }
}
```

**Profile View:**

The profile view has a section for comments:

```
<!-- START TIMELINE -->        
<ul class="timeline">                           
</ul>
```

Here is the ajax call I make to append the profile_posts results which is basically HTML data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getposts(0);   
    $("#load_more").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).data('val');
            getposts(page);
    }); 
});

var getposts = function(page){
    $("#loader").show();
    $("#load_text").hide();
    $.ajax({
        url:'<?=base_url("user/get_posts").'/'.$username ?>',
        type:'GET',
        data: {'<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>':'<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>', page:page}
    }).done(function(response){
        $(".timeline").append(response);
        $("#loader").hide();
        $("#load_text").show();
        $('#load_more').data('val', ($('#load_more').data('val')+1));
    });
};
```

**profile_posts view:**

Here is where I think I am doing it all wrong, but I followed the advice of someone else.

```
foreach ($profile_posts as $posts)
{
if($posts->post_type == 'post')
{
    echo '<li id="li1" class="all-posts posts li1">
        <div class="timeline-badge secondary"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>    </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">                                              
                <div class="timeline-title">
                    <div class="timeline-post">
                        <a href="'.$posts->profile.'" class="margin-right5">
                            <img class="img-circle" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/38d618563e55e6082adf4c8f8c13f3e4?s=40&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="..." height="48" width="48">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-post">';
                        if($posts->poster == $posts->profile)
                        {                                       
                            echo '<a href="'.$posts->poster.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->poster.'</a> wrote a post';                                        
                        }
                        else 
                        {                                       
                            echo '<a href="'.$posts->poster.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->poster.'</a> wrote a post on <a href="'.$posts->profile.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->profile.'s</a> timline';
                        }                                                                                       
                            echo '<p><small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> '.timespan($posts->datetime, time(), 1).' ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>                                         
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">'
                .$posts->post_text.
                '<hr>
                <div class="timeline-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default like like-btn'.$posts->post_id.'" value="'.$posts->post_id.'"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up margin-right5"></i>'.$posts->likes.'</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dislike dislike-btn'.$posts->post_id.'" value="'.$posts->post_id.'"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down margin-right5"></i>0</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-comment margin-right5"></i>Comment</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-share-alt margin-right5"></i>Share</button>                                      
                </div>                                
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>';                 
}
if($posts->post_type == 'video')
{
    echo '<li id="li2" class="all-posts videos li2">
        <div class="timeline-badge danger"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">                                          
                <div class="timeline-title">
                    <div class="timeline-post">
                        <a href="'.$posts->profile.'" class="margin-right5">
                            <img class="img-circle" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/38d618563e55e6082adf4c8f8c13f3e4?s=40&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="..." height="48" width="48">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-post">';
                        if($posts->poster == $posts->profile)
                        {
                            echo '<a href="'.$posts->poster.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->poster.'</a> posted '.$posts->total_files.' new '.($posts->total_files == 1 ? 'video' : 'videos');
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            echo '<a href="'.$posts->poster.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->poster.'</a> posted '.$posts->total_files.' new '.($posts->total_files == 1 ? 'video' : 'videos').' on <a href="'.$posts->profile.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->profile.'s</a> timline'; 
                        }                                                                                       
                        echo '<p><small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> '.timespan($posts->datetime, time(), 1).' ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>                                     
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">'
                .$posts->post_text.
                '<hr>
                <div class="timeline-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default like like-btn'.$posts->post_id.'" value="'.$posts->post_id.'"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up margin-right5"></i>0</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dislike dislike-btn'.$posts->post_id.'" value="'.$posts->post_id.'"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down margin-right5"></i>0</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-comment margin-right5"></i>Comment</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-share-alt margin-right5"></i>Share</button>                                      
                </div>                                
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>';
}
if($posts->post_type == 'image')
{
    echo '<li id="li3" class="all-posts images li3">
        <div class="timeline-badge info"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">                                          
                <div class="timeline-title">
                    <div class="timeline-post">
                        <a href="'.$posts->profile.'" class="margin-right5">
                            <img class="img-circle" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/38d618563e55e6082adf4c8f8c13f3e4?s=40&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="..." height="48" width="48">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-post">';
                        if($posts->poster == $posts->profile)
                        {
                            echo '<a href="'.$posts->poster.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->poster.'</a> posted '.$posts->total_files.' '.($posts->total_files == 1 ? 'image' : 'images');
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            echo '<a href="'.$posts->poster.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->poster.'</a> posted '.$posts->total_files.' '.($posts->total_files == 1 ? 'image' : 'images').' on <a href="'.$posts->profile.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->profile.'s</a> timline'; 
                        }                                                                                       
                        echo '<p><small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> '.timespan($posts->datetime, time(), 1).' ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>                                     
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">'
                .$posts->post_text.                                                       
            '</div>
            <hr>
            <div class="timeline-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default like like-btn'.$posts->post_id.'" value="'.$posts->post_id.'"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up margin-right5"></i>0</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dislike dislike-btn'.$posts->post_id.'" value="'.$posts->post_id.'"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down margin-right5"></i>0</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-comment margin-right5"></i>Comment</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-share-alt margin-right5"></i>Share</button>                                      
            </div>      
        </div>
    </li>';
}
if($posts->post_type == 'image_upload')
{
    echo '<li id="li3" class="all-posts images li3">
        <div class="timeline-badge info"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">                                          
                <div class="timeline-title">
                    <div class="timeline-post">
                        <a href="'.$posts->profile.'" class="margin-right5">
                            <img class="img-circle" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/38d618563e55e6082adf4c8f8c13f3e4?s=40&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="..." height="48" width="48">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-post">';
                        if($posts->poster == $posts->profile)
                        {
                            echo '<a href="'.$posts->poster.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->poster.'</a> uploaded '.$posts->total_files.' new '.($posts->total_files == 1 ? 'image' : 'images');
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            echo '<a href="'.$posts->poster.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->poster.'</a> uploaded '.$posts->total_files.' new '.($posts->total_files == 1 ? 'image' : 'images').' on <a href="'.$posts->profile.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->profile.'s</a> timline'; 
                        }                                                                                       
                        echo '<p><small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> '.timespan($posts->datetime, time(), 1).' ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>                                     
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">'
                .$posts->post_text.                                                       
            '</div>
            <hr>
            <div class="timeline-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default like like-btn'.$posts->post_id.'" value="'.$posts->post_id.'"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up margin-right5"></i>0</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dislike dislike-btn'.$posts->post_id.'" value="'.$posts->post_id.'"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down margin-right5"></i>0</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-comment margin-right5"></i>Comment</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-share-alt margin-right5"></i>Share</button>                                      
            </div>      
        </div>
    </li>';
}
if($posts->post_type == 'gif')
{
    echo '<li id="li4" class="all-posts gifs li4">
        <div class="timeline-badge warning"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>    </div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">                                          
                <div class="timeline-title">
                    <div class="timeline-post">
                        <a href="'.$posts->profile.'" class="margin-right5">
                            <img class="img-circle" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/38d618563e55e6082adf4c8f8c13f3e4?s=40&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="..." height="48" width="48">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-post">';
                        if($posts->poster == $posts->profile)
                        {
                            echo '<a href="'.$posts->poster.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->poster.'</a> posted '.$posts->total_files.' new '.($posts->total_files == 1 ? 'GIF' : 'GIFs');
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            echo '<a href="'.$posts->poster.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->poster.'</a> posted '.$posts->total_files.' new '.($posts->total_files == 1 ? 'GIF' : 'GIFs').' on <a href="'.$posts->profile.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->profile.'s</a> timline'; 
                        }                                                                                       
                        echo '<p><small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> '.timespan($posts->datetime, time(), 1).' ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>                                     
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">'
                .$posts->post_text.
                '<hr>
                <div class="timeline-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default like like-btn'.$posts->post_id.'" value="'.$posts->post_id.'"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up margin-right5"></i>0</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dislike dislike-btn'.$posts->post_id.'" value="'.$posts->post_id.'"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down margin-right5"></i>0</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-comment margin-right5"></i>Comment</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-share-alt margin-right5"></i>Share</button>                                      
                </div>                                
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>';
}
if($posts->post_type == 'playlist')
{
    echo '<li id="li5" class="all-posts playlists li5">
        <div class="timeline-badge success"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></div>
        <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">                                          
                <div class="timeline-title">
                    <div class="timeline-post">
                        <a href="'.$posts->profile.'" class="margin-right5">
                            <img class="img-circle" src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/38d618563e55e6082adf4c8f8c13f3e4?s=40&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" alt="..." height="48" width="48">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-post">';
                        if($posts->poster == $posts->profile)
                        {
                            echo '<a href="'.$posts->poster.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->poster.'</a> posted '.$posts->total_files.' new '.($posts->total_files == 1 ? 'playlist' : 'playlists');
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            echo '<a href="'.$posts->poster.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->poster.'</a> posted '.$posts->total_files.' new '.($posts->total_files == 1 ? 'playlist' : 'playlists').' on <a href="'.$posts->profile.'" class="stream-username">'.$posts->profile.'s</a> timline'; 
                        }                                                                                       
                        echo '<p><small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> '.timespan($posts->datetime, time(), 1).' ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>                                     
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">'
                .$posts->post_text.
                '<hr>
                <div class="timeline-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default like like-btn'.$posts->post_id.'" value="'.$posts->post_id.'"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up margin-right5"></i>0</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dislike dislike-btn'.$posts->post_id.'" value="'.$posts->post_id.'"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down margin-right5"></i>0</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-comment margin-right5"></i>Comment</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-share-alt margin-right5"></i>Share</button>       
                    <input type="hidden"" name="post_id" class="post_id" value="'.$posts->post_id.'">                              
                </div>                                
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>';
}
?>
<script>
    $(function(){         
        var post_id = <?php echo $posts->post_id; ?>; 
        var like = 'like';
        var dislike = 'dislike';

        $('.like-btn'+post_id).click(function(){
            $('.dislike-btn'+post_id).removeClass('btn-danger'); 
            $(this).removeClass('btn-default');   
            $(this).addClass('btn-success');
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:'<?=base_url("user/post_rate")?>',
                data:{'<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>':'<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>',rate:like,post_id:post_id},
                success: function(response){
                    var likes = parseInt($('.like-btn'+post_id).text());
                    var liked = parseInt(response);
                    var totalLikes = likes + liked; 
                    var dislikes = parseInt($('.dislike-btn'+post_id).text());
                    if(dislikes == 0){
                        var totalDislikes = 0;
                    } else {
                        var totalDislikes = dislikes - 1;
                    }                        
                    $('.dislike-btn'+post_id).addClass('btn-default');                     
                    $('.like-btn'+post_id).html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up margin-right5"></i> '+totalLikes);
                    $('.dislike-btn'+post_id).html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up margin-right5"></i> '+totalDislikes);
                }
            });
        });
        $('.dislike-btn'+post_id).click(function(){
            $('.like-btn'+post_id).removeClass('btn-success');
            $(this).removeClass('btn-default');
            $(this).addClass('btn-danger');
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:'<?=base_url("user/post_rate")?>',
                data:{'<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>':'<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>',rate:dislike,post_id:post_id},
                success: function(response){
                    var dislikes = parseInt($('.dislike-btn'+post_id).text());
                    var disliked = parseInt(response);
                    var totalDislikes = dislikes + disliked;   
                    var likes = parseInt($('.like-btn'+post_id).text());
                    if(likes == 0){
                        var totalLikes = 0;
                    } else {
                        var totalLikes = likes - 1;
                    }     
                    $('.like-btn'+post_id).addClass('btn-default');
                    $('.dislike-btn'+post_id).html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up margin-right5"></i> '+totalDislikes);
                    $('.like-btn'+post_id).html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up margin-right5"></i> '+totalLikes);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
}
?>
<script>
function getlikes(){
    $(".like").each(function(){
        var post_id = $(this).val();
        var self = $(this);
        $.ajax({
           method:"GET",
           url:'<?=base_url("user/get_post_like_count")?>',
           data:{'<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>':'<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>',post_id:post_id},
           success:function(data){
               var json = JSON.parse(data);
               //alert(json.className); 
               $(self).addClass(json.likeClass);         
               $(self).html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up margin-right5"></i> '+json.likes); //updating total counts
           }
        });
    });
};

function getdislikes(){    
    $(".dislike").each(function(){
        var post_id = $(this).val();
        var self = $(this);
        $.ajax({
           method:"GET",
           url:'<?=base_url("user/get_post_dislike_count")?>',
           data:{'<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>':'<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>',post_id:post_id},
           success:function(data){
               var json = JSON.parse(data);
               //alert(json.className); 
               $(self).addClass(json.dislikeClass);         
               $(self).html('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up margin-right5"></i> '+json.dislikes); //updating total counts
           }
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() { 
    getlikes();
    getdislikes();          
    var parent = $('.timeline'), list = $('li', parent);
    $('#showAll').click(function(){
        list.show("slow");
        $(".show-posts").removeClass("active");
        $("#showAll").addClass("active");
    });
    $('.show-posts').click(function(){
        var target = '.li'+$(this).attr('target');
        list.not(target).hide("slow");
        $(target,parent).show("slow");
        if(target == '.li1') {
            $("#showAll").removeClass("active");
            $(".show-posts").removeClass("active");
            $("#filterPosts").addClass("active");
        }
        if(target == '.li2') {
            $("#showAll").removeClass("active");
            $(".show-posts").removeClass("active");
            $("#filterVideos").addClass("active");
        }
        if(target == '.li3') {
            $("#showAll").removeClass("active");
            $(".show-posts").removeClass("active");
            $("#filterImages").addClass("active");
        }

    });

});
```

My end goal here is to load the profile post as quickly as possible with the like/dislike data. I am not looking for someone to do the work for me (unless you want too :) ) but any help would be appreciated. Can someone help me refactor my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as you already figured out:

> the problem is that I am making an ajax call for each comment which is taking a total of 60 sec to load all data.

The problem here is that a browser only allows just a certain amount of ajax-calls at a time. You can view it here: http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=1 ("Connections per hostname"; For the newest Chrome-version it would be 6 at a time).

Another problem is that you open one connection for each of your comment. This is very time-consuming. If you open the dev-tools, go to the tab "Timeline" in Chrome, something like "Network-Analysis" in Firefox, you will see every of your comment loading and taking its time.

So i would suggest your primary goal should be: Reduce the requests.

The way you do this is your thing. Here are just 2 ideas i have:

1. You can write down the likes- and dislikes-part in CodeIgniter as well and include it already in the comments-section so you just need one ajax-call.
2. You can create one site (e.g. profile_posts itself) which loads all the posts including its likes / dislikes and output it all in JSON. All further handling would be in JS (correct HTML-Markup etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I will try the 2 suggestions. My problem with the first one is when I try to inner join on my likes table it only brings back the comments the logged in user has liked. I will keep trying a few things, but i am totally lost.

Comment: I was able to implement number 1 and make only one ajax call, but I am running into another issue. I think I will create a new question for it. Thank you so much!